# What are all the default items in transport package

Tags: publishing, deployer, publishtransaction, deployer-extension

Want to Know some general information on transport package like default items in transport package when publishing a component, page, component template etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The transport package format is undocumented, and not a valid extension point - therefore I doubt you'll find much information publicly.

However... it's really easy to figure this out, as all you need is a copy of a few Transport Packages and the ability to unzip files. You can easily configure your deployer to keep copies of the successful transport packages (just read through the comments in cd_deployer_conf.xml, or read [this answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/5251/33)).

Do be aware that the reason why this format is undocumented is so that SDL can change the data format at will - and this happens quite often, as capabilities on CM or CD change over time.

Comment: Yes Nuno Linhares, this is how am getting the information now from ZIP.